# R Read In Data Subset Based on CSV

Tags: r, csv

Let us say if you have a .DTA OR .SAV file with 1,000 VARIABLES. This file is called "TOTAL-DATA" You also have .CSV file called "SOME-DATA" that contains a column named KEEP; In the KEEP column is the names of the 25 VARIABLES from "TOTAL-DATA"

Is there a way in R to read in the .DTA or .SAV file; and then subset to the VARIABLES in the KEEP column if "TOTAL-DATA" ?

Comment: @Parfait thank you i know these are not R files. that is not the point of the quest. the question is about leading in those files and then subsetting variables using a column from  .CSV thanks though

Comment: @parfait did you read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is `.sav`, then `read_sav` from `haven` can be used.  It also have the argument `col_select` which can take a vector of column names.  The documentation from `?read_sav` shows

> col_select - One or more selection expressions, like in dplyr::select(). Use c() or list() to use more than one expression. See ?dplyr::select for details on available selection options. Only the specified columns will be read from data_file.

The strategy would be to read the `.csv` file, extract the 'KEEP' column as a `vector` and feed into the `col_select` of 'read_sav`

```
library(readr)
library(haven)
library(dplyr)
cols_to_select <- read_csv("SOME-DATA.csv") %>%
                     pull(KEEP)

df1 <- read_sav("TOTAL-DATA.sav", col_select = cols_to_select)
```

NOTE: IF it s a `.dta` file, use `read_dta` from `haven`.  It also have the same `col_select` argument

Comment: when i read in the "TOTAL-DATA.sav" it takes almost 15 minutes for it is such a big file. I wonder, is there a way to only read in select variables using cols_to_select? or is that not really a possibility?

Comment: @bvowe It says the `col_select` will read only those columns.  Is it not the case?